# How to render a View using AJAX in Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC and I need to make an asynchronous call to the server and refresh only a piece of the page.

What I actually have is a Controller that returns a String. I call the Controller using JQuery ([.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)) function.

The problem with my solution is that I'm not able to render a JSP like I do when I use ModelAndView as return type.

Is there any way to return a View already rendered?

Thanks in advance.

Neuquino

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can put this piece of page into a separate JSP and return a `ModelAndView` pointing to it from your method. There are no difference between AJAX and non-AJAX calls from that point.

Comment: I have same requirement as OP, and this sounds promising but I'm not quite following... could you elaborate, or link to a tutorial that takes this approach?

Comment: I'm dumb. After playing around for a minute it clicked what you wanted.  :)  I'll work up a short example here in a minute once I get something working.

Answer (score 61):

This answer is to just confirm that the answer by axtavt works.  It took me a minute to realize what he was suggesting, so I thought I'd post a code-snippet to help out anyone coming along behind me.  Kudos go to him, though!  :)

**MyController.java**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/mainView" )
    public ModelAndView getMainView( ... ) {        
        /* do all your normal stuff here to build your primary NON-ajax view
         * in the same way you always do
         */             
    }

    /* this is the conroller's part of the magic; I'm just using a simple GET but you
     * could just as easily do a POST here, obviously
     */
    @RequestMapping( method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/subView" )
    public ModelAndView getSubView( Model model ) {
        model.addAttribute( "user", "Joe Dirt" );
        model.addAttribute( "time", new Date() );
        return new ModelAndView( "subView" );
    }

}
```

**mainView.jsp**

```
(...)

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doAjaxPost() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "subView",
            success: function(response) {
                $("#subViewDiv").html( response );
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value="GO!" onclick="doAjaxPost();" />
<div id="subViewDiv"></div>

(...)
```

**subView.jsp**

```
(...)

<h3>
    User Access Details
</h3>

<p>
    ${user} accessed the system on ${time}
</p>

(...)
```

And that's it!  A thing of beauty; up to now, doing AJAX in Spring has been a huge pain... parsing big @ResponseBody's, building huge sets of HTML by concatenating stuff in JS... ugh... I can't believe how simple and awesome this approach is -- and wasn't aware of it until just now!  :)

Comment: Absolutely great! With this we basically can forget about js at all, since the end result rendered in html whenever required we can just substitute divs with required chunks from jsp and I personally believe jsp is much better maintainable than jquery/js code. Everything great is usually simple.

Comment: Awesome.... I had been going through pain for last three days over using JS to spit out HTML content. This solution is awesome. Thanks for the explanation. I wish I could vote this more higher.

Comment: Thus question with its answers must be really set status as protected. ;-)

Comment: Yes it's not bad. It's even a very smart solution. I would say, it's THE solution: +1

Comment: great explanation, just one question. Can use dialog/pop up window to show the code: $("#subViewDiv").html( response );

Comment: yeah you should be able to use a dialog to show the code AFTER you add the response to the DIV (like my example shows).  Back in the day that's exactly what I did using JQuery's API to display a modal with the AJAX info.