# AJAX mechanics when updating view parts

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I am only learning ajax atm and so far my best application of it is form validation.

My conceptual question is what exactly the best way to deal with design issues when for example we need to update a certain page fragment.

Basic scenario:

We have page 1 and page 2 where both pages have the same menu and footer.
Page 1 contains just neatly formatted table with content of some statistics and page 2 contains messages. We want to implement ajax so that menu stays there on top when we move from page 1 to page 2 and vice-versa.

For instance we have request handler which returns JSON from server. For page 1 ajax request, our server returns just table data, for page 2 messages.

**The confusion is how and where to store design information to format page fragment of the returning data correctly? What is the common strategy - is it to manually apply css on data on "succeed" event within ajax method? But does it not introduce disjointness between client and server as server also applies the formatting itself for standard requests? And if the content data returning from ajax request demands dramatically different design like in example I gave you, that means externalizing the majority of html and css application into javaScript which I personally believe will be a problem if you are:**

1. Updating big fragments of a page - code becoming unmaintainable on client side, or we need template engine on client side too.
2. Using template engines on server-side and even plain .jsp in case of java. - where we will get for example syntax and structure of view chunks of "apache tiles" and then have to write plain html with css for client side ajax response handling section.

Of course we can return XML but it seems the development trajectory goes in favor of JSON, as in case of Spring Framework for example the converter does the job automatically..

I believe this is a little concern for vaadin or GWT users, but I am taking side for traditional MVC and not using code generators.

To narrow down the context I am particularly interested how people deal with this in Spring MVC with JSP and Spring MVC + Apache Tiles.

Also I can possibly send HTML design metadata with data in JSON back to client, or this will be really horrible thing to do? But again disparity with view rendering technologies on server side.

I believe I am missing something very fundamental and important in here.

Thank You,

Comment: Answer found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816080/how-to-render-a-view-using-ajax-in-spring-mvc?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you will be re-using this menu and footer across many pages in your system, then I do indeed recommend using a template engine like Thymeleaf, JSP tags, or Apache Tiles.

But I think what you are really curious about is how to manage transitions of partial page content through AJAX, and you (rightly) do not want to make the controller layer responsible for generating page fragments.

Here, you generate a single page that contains **both** the page 1 table, and the page 2 messages:

```
<div id="page1" style="display: none">
    <%--table structure, without data--%>
</div>

<div id="page2" style="display: none">
    <%--message display, without message content--%>
</div>
```

Now, you create two Spring MVC controller methods that return raw data in JSON format, one that returns your table data, and another that returns your messages.

Finally, write your Javascript handlers that invoke your controllers, populate the data, and manage the page transitions. I will use jQuery syntax for brevity:

```
$.getJSON( 'mycontroller/page1', params, function( jsonData ) {
    // populate table data
    $( '#page1' ).show();
    $( '#page2' ).hide();
} );
```

to show the table data, and:

```
$.getJSON( 'mycontroller/page2', params, function( jsonData ) {
    // populate message text
    $( '#page1' ).hide();
    $( '#page2' ).show();
} );
```

to show the messages.

Of course, now that you are using Javascript, you can replace show() with fancy animated transitions like slide or fadeIn, if you wish.