# Add dynamic content to a dialog, page not loaded

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, jsp, spring-mvc

Habitually, to display dialog windows for create a new object, i define it and call it directly in my jsp.
So i don't have any problem to feed model attribute of spring form tag.

Now i search a way to editing a object.
I can't create full modal directly in my jsp.
I need a way to create a part of the jdialog, and add a other part dynamicly.
Is it possible with spring and jquery?

My try

```
$('#updateUser').dialog({
autoOpen: false,
height: 660,
    width: 715,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
  "Save": function() {

  },
  Cancel: function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    },
    close: function() {
    }
    });

$("#updateUserButton]").click(function() {

        var userName = $(this).closest('tr').data('userName');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/secure/admin/ajaxEditingUser",
            data: {userame: userName}


        }).done(function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });

        $('#updateUser').dialog("open");
    });

<div id="updateUser" title="Update user" style="display:none">
    <div id="ajaxUserBloc"></div>
</div>
```

My java controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/secure/admin/ajaxEditingUser")
public String showAjaxEditingUser(Model model, @RequestParam("username") String userName){

    UserBean userBean = userBeanMap.get(userName);
    model.addAttribute("editingUser", userBean);

    return "ajaxEditingUserForm";
}
```

I have a jsp named: ajaxEditingUserForm

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<form:form id="userModelForm" modelAttribute="editingUser">
...
</form:form>
```

Controller is correctly called, i saw it in debug mode.
In the done method, data is empty... i was thinking i would get the content of ajaxEditingUserForm feeded by editingUser bean

It's like the forward to the jsp page is not done...

tried
    $("#ajaxUpdateUserBloc").load("${ajaxEditingUserForm}" + "?username="+userName);

same problem

should work like we can see in this example: [How to render a View using AJAX in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816080/how-to-render-a-view-using-ajax-in-spring-mvc?lq=1)

when i debug more deeply, i get:

Could not resolve view with name 'ajaxEditingUserForm' in servlet with name 'UserServlet'

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>classpath:spring/web-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Have you tried to go directly to `/secure/admin/ajaxEditingUser?username=<username>` in your browser? Does this return anything?

Comment: tried and return nothing i really don't understand why.. should work like this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816080/how-to-render-a-view-using-ajax-in-spring-mvc?lq=1

Comment: Sounds as though the jsp isn't rendering any output. Can you see any errors in the server logs? Perhaps try stripping the jsp right back - to just return a simple 'Hello world' string. Then see whether you can get that to come back.

Comment: my jsp file have only hello string... all my jsp file are in view folder. I tried to return a return new ModelAndView("/view/ajaxEditingUserForm");  or ModelAndView("ajaxEditingUserForm"); For my normal page i only returned name jsp i tried "/view/ajaxEditingReportForm"; and "ajaxEditingReportForm"; same result nothing about that in the log file