# How to use ResponseEntity object inside thymeleaf modal

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a spring mvc page having multiple rows as shown below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/53f0Q.jpg

'Details' link gets generated inside a loop

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary" id="updateCategory"
th:onclick="'javascript:openModal(\'' + ${category.id} + '\');'">
<i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i> Details
```

Code for openModal function:

```
function openModal(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url : "/admin/categories/update?catId=" + id,
        success : function(data) {
            $("#addCategoryModal").modal("show");
        },
        error : function(data) {
        }
    });
};
```

Contoller code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/update", produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Category> getUser(@RequestParam("catId") int id) {
        Category category = categoryService.findOne(id);
        if (category == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Category>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Category>(category, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I would like that when details button is clicked a modal should open with pre-populated data from category object that gets returned from controller.

My question is - above code executes fine and as result of ajax call i get a json object in javascript function, how can i use it to populate the modal form? Can i somehow set value  of `th:object="${category}"` by using the returned json object from controller?

Code for modal form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/admin/category/save}"
                    th:object="${category}" method=post>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" /> <label for="title">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{categoryName}"
                            class="form-control mb-1" placeholder="Enter Category Name"
                            id="categoryName"></input>
                        <div class="error" id="categoryNameError"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="saveCategory">Save
                            Changes</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: I think you have two options, one is populating that fields when AJAX call on success (using javascript), another one passing category as MODEL ? have you tried any of em?

Comment: You can also check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816080/how-to-render-a-view-using-ajax-in-spring-mvc

It is possible to do an Ajax call to a spring mvc controller and set the response html with jquery to your own div. So in your case you can create an own html for the category details page and implement a normal mvc controller which has a categoryForm as @ModelAttribute. This response you will then render in the modal where you load the html you received from the server.